# How to plot displacement-time graph when a piecewise function of velocity is given?

Tags: plotting

Given a piecewise function of `v[t]`, how to plot its displacement `x[t]`?

```
ClearAll[v, x];
v[t_] := 2 t /; t < 10;
v[t_] := 20 /; 10 <= t < 25;
v[t_] := t - 5 /; 25 <= t < 35;
v[t_] := 30 /; 35 <= t < 50;
v[t_] := -7 t + 380 /; 50 <= t < 55;
v[t_] := -5 /; 55 <= t < 65;
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t], {t, 0, 10}] /; t <= 10;
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t], {t, 10, 25}] + x[10] /; 10 < t <= 25;
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t], {t, 25, 35}] + x[25] /; 25 < t <= 35;
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t], {t, 35, 50}] + x[35] /; 35 < t <= 50;
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t], {t, 50, 55}] + x[50] /; 50 < t <= 55;
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t], {t, 55, 65}] + x[55] /; 55 < t <= 65;
Plot[{v[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 65}]
```

The above code produces a lot of errors:

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in
> {0.00132786,0,10}.

> NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.0013278571428571428` cannot be used as
> an iterator.

> etc...

Comment: you can't integrate with respect to a number. When you do `x[10]` for example, then what do you expected the call to `x[t_]` to be?  `t` will be a number, and then you are doing integrate with respect to this `t` which is a number.

Comment: @Nasser: Thank your very much. Your comment is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
v[t_] := Which[0 <= t < 10, 2 t, 10 < t <= 25, 20, 25 < t <= 35, 
   t - 5];
x[t_] := Integrate[v[t1], {t1, 0, t}];
Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 35}]
```

returning the plot:

[image]

Comments:

1. I intentionally did not include all your details in the definition of `v[t]`. First, it is not difficult to make it based on my solution. Second, the scale of `x[t]` is such that details of the behavior will become badly visible on it.
2. I do not recommend showing `v[t]` and `x[t]` on the same plot due to their very different scales.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Only for future purposes.

```
ClearAll[v, x, scale];
scale = 1/50;
v[t_] := 2 t /; t < 10;
v[t_] := 20 /; 10 <= t < 25;
v[t_] := t - 5 /; 25 <= t < 35;
v[t_] := 30 /; 35 <= t < 50;
v[t_] := -7 t + 380 /; 50 <= t < 55;
v[t_] := -5 /; 55 <= t < 65;
x[t_] := scale Integrate[v[u], {u, 0, t}] /; t <= 10;
x[t_] := scale Integrate[v[u], {u, 10, t}] + x[10] /; 10 < t <= 25;
x[t_] := scale Integrate[v[u], {u, 25, t}] + x[25] /; 25 < t <= 35;
x[t_] := scale Integrate[v[u], {u, 35, t}] + x[35] /; 35 < t <= 50;
x[t_] := scale Integrate[v[u], {u, 50, t}] + x[50] /; 50 < t <= 55;
x[t_] := scale Integrate[v[u], {u, 55, t}] + x[55] /; 55 < t <= 65;
Plot[{v[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 65}]
```